# Adding a field in Document in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
 database = {
  '__v': 78,
  '_id': ObjectId('5de4218d6a2be815b9e215e1'),

 'services': [
          {
           '_id': ObjectId('5de4218e6a2be815b9e2186d'),
           'name':'shivam',
          },

         {
          '_id': ObjectId('5de4218e6a2be815b9e2181e'),
           'name': 'Shivi'.
         }
        ]
 }




catalogues.update_one({'services._id': ObjectId(id)},{'$set': {'age': 
   "30"}},False,True)
```

This is one of the documents in mongodb.collection. How can I add a field 'age' in the dictionaries placed in services(list/array) in pymongo and update it in the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting data to nested array in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64097253/inserting-data-to-nested-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution in pymongo. The link you provided is in javascript.

Comment: The request should work the same since it's both a MongoDB query

Comment: But it didn't. I tried this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)

```
catalogues.update_one({'services._id': ObjectId(x_id)}, {'$set': {'services.$.age': '30'}})
```

Full example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId
import pprint

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
catalogues = db.catalogues

catalogues.insert_one({
    '__v': 78,
    '_id': ObjectId('5de4218d6a2be815b9e215e1'),

    'services': [
        {
            '_id': ObjectId('5de4218e6a2be815b9e2186d'),
            'name': 'shivam'
        },

        {
            '_id': ObjectId('5de4218e6a2be815b9e2181e'),
            'name': 'Shivi'
        }
    ]
})

x_id = '5de4218e6a2be815b9e2181e'

catalogues.update_one({'services._id': ObjectId(x_id)}, {'$set': {'services.$.age': '30'}})
```

result:

```
{'__v': 78,
 '_id': ObjectId('5de4218d6a2be815b9e215e1'),
 'services': [{'_id': ObjectId('5de4218e6a2be815b9e2186d'), 'name': 'shivam'},
              {'_id': ObjectId('5de4218e6a2be815b9e2181e'),
               'age': '30',
               'name': 'Shivi'}]}
```